# Erlang record syntax with single quotes

Tags: erlang, records

Can someone explain the single quotes (' ') in this Erlang record syntax?

```
#'queue.declare'{queue = <<"hello">>}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this expression, `'queue.declare'` is [the record's name](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id81622), and therefore must be [an atom](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66445).

> An atom should be enclosed in single quotes (') if it does not begin
>   with a lower-case letter or if it **contains other characters than
>   alphanumeric characters, underscore (_), or @.**

Answer (score 0):

`'`s are for atoms and `"`s are for strings. `'`s and `"`s are not interchangeable, so use them in the appropriate places.

If you want to read more, read: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html